# using delphi xe7 form(VCL) in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe7

Is there some possibility to use Delphi xe7 form in Delphi 7 project, without create DLL file? I found "Monkey-Mixer" which allows to use FMX form in VCL project, and I wonder is there same tool for use new VCL forms in older versions of Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some possibility to use Delphi XE7 form in Delphi 7 project, without creating DLL file?

No there is not. You cannot link code from different versions of Delphi into the same executable.

Comment: If you were willing to invest the time, is it *theoretically* possible to use {$IF Defined(D7)} and {$IF Defined(XE7)} to enclose bits of the form code incompatible between versions? Minor changes in the form code might leave it compilable in both IDEs. Just a thought...

Comment: @AlainD I don't think you've quite understood what the asker is asking. He wants to build/link XE7 code in D7.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Still, I was wondering whether it was possible to create two similar forms (one generating a DFM, the other a FMX, both generating a PAS), and sort of "refactor" the PAS into a common "super"-PAS file with conditional compilation. The effort-to-benefit ratio is all wrong, but even so...surely it could work?